# Keeping unmodified copy of dom node issues

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am attempting to make a copy of a dom node so I can restore its state after modification later. In this case after the modal window has closed.

The weird thing is that after two times of opening the modal, clicking the #show_reg_form button and closing the modal. The modal_body_initial variable seems to be getting modified as the next time I open the modal window its in the modified state.

I have also tried with and without this line inside the on hide function.

```
modal_body = modal_auth.find('.modal-body');
```

Thoughts on what I'm going wrong here?

```
$(document)
.on('ready', function(){
    var modal_auth = $('#modal_auth');
    var modal_body = modal_auth.find('.modal-body');
    var modal_body_initial = modal_body.clone();

    $('#modal_auth').on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {
        modal_body.replaceWith(modal_body_initial);
        modal_body = modal_auth.find('.modal-body');
    });
})
.on('click', '#show_reg_form, #show_login_form', function(){
    var button = $(this);
    var form = button.next();
    var parent = button.parent();

    form.hide();
    form.removeClass('hidden');

    parent.siblings(':not(.custom-header)').each(function(){
        $(this).hide();
    });

    form.slideDown(function(){
        button.slideUp();
    });
})
```

Comment: Posting relevant parts of your HTML would be helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If what you are trying to do is preserve the HTML of `modal_body_initial`,
 perhaps something like the following will work for you:

```
$(document).on('ready', function(){
    var modal_auth = $('#modal_auth');
    var modal_body = modal_auth.find('.modal-body');
    var modal_body_initial = modal_body.html(); // <------- EDIT

    $('#modal_auth').on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {
        modal_body.html(modal_body_initial); // <------- EDIT
        modal_body = modal_auth.find('.modal-body');
    });
});
```